Hash and merge join never finishes, loops does
I ran into issues with one query that used to work fine in the past, but now it is so slow so it basically never finishes (perhaps in some hours, beyond any timeouts).
The query is like
select ky.issuer_id from T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS ky 
inner join T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST lst on lst.ISSUER_ID_SIX = ky.ISSUER_ID_SIX AND lst.ISSUER_ID_BBG = ky.ISSUER_ID_BBG
WHERE ky.ISSUER_ID_RDE is not null

And its live execution plan looks like that

The live execution still stuck at the Hash Match join step.
However, if I force a nested loops join instead
select ky.issuer_id from T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS ky 
inner loop join T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST lst on lst.ISSUER_ID_SIX = ky.ISSUER_ID_SIX AND lst.ISSUER_ID_BBG = ky.ISSUER_ID_BBG
WHERE ky.ISSUER_ID_RDE is not null

Then it finishes in a second, as expected:

I already tried create some covering indices to include all the join and selection attributes, but nothing helped there. To me it looks like a hash join of 100k and 300k rows should be a piece of cake for the server.
Moreover, if I remove any of the two join conditions, the query works fine:
select ky.issuer_id from T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS ky 
inner join T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST lst on /*lst.ISSUER_ID_SIX = ky.ISSUER_ID_SIX AND*/ lst.ISSUER_ID_BBG = ky.ISSUER_ID_BBG
WHERE ky.ISSUER_ID_RDE is not null


The joining columns are VARCHAR(20), could it have any impact on the join?

In both cases it looks like you don't have relevant indexes; the first plan shows 2 scans and the latter a key lookup. Can you post the DDL for the tables and their indexes?

Have you tried using EXISTS operator instead? Since you are not returning any data from the 2nd table, might as well give EXISTS operator a go. More often than not in such cases EXISTS operator outperform JOINs.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? [mre]

Looks like the hash join operator itself is taking the time. Is it spilling?

Rewrite as :
select ky.issuer_id 
from   T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS AS ky 
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1/0
              FROM   T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST AS lst 
              WHERE  lst.ISSUER_ID_SIX = ky.ISSUER_ID_SIX AND 
                     lst.ISSUER_ID_BBG = ky.ISSUER_ID_BBG AND
                     ky.ISSUER_ID_RDE is not null);

Create theses index if not exists :
-- index for ky : 
CREATE INDEX X_Jan_Drozen_T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS_001
   ON  T_MASTER_ISSUER_KEYS (ISSUER_ID_RDE, ISSUER_ID_SIX, ISSUER_ID_BBG) INCLUDE (issuer_id);
-- index for lst :
CREATE INDEX X_Jan_Drozen_T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST_001
   ON  T_ISSUER_SECURITY_LIST (ISSUER_ID_SIX, ISSUER_ID_BBG) ;

